# What are the various ways code may be 'vectorized'?

Tags: c, vectorization

I usually hear the term vectorized functions in one of two ways:

- In a very high-level language when the data is passed all-at-once (or at least, in bulk chunks) to a lower-level library that does the calculations in faster way. An example of this would be python's use of `numpy` for array/LA-related stuff.
- At the lowest level, when using a specific machine instruction or procedure that makes heavy use of them (such as YMM, ZMM, XMM register instructions).

However, it seems like the term is passed around quite generally, and I wanted to know if there's a third (or even more) ways in which it's used. And this would just be, for example, passing multiple values to a function rather than one (usually done via an array) for example:

```
// non-'vectorized'
#include <stdio.h>

int squared(int num) {
    return num*num;
}

int main(void) {
    int nums[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(nums)/sizeof(*nums); i++) {
        int n_squared = squared(nums[i]);
        printf("%d^2 = %d\n", nums[i], n_squared);
    }
}
```

```
// 'vectorized'
#include <stdio.h>

void squared(int num[], int size) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        *(num +i) = num[i] * num[i];
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int nums[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    squared(nums, sizeof(nums)/sizeof(*nums));
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(nums)/sizeof(*nums); i++) {
        printf("Squared=%d\n", nums[i]);
    }
}
```

Is the above considered 'vectorized code'? Is there a more formal/better definition of what makes something vectorized or not?

Comment: Opinion only:  [vector](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs099/2004fa/Notes/wk6.pdf), in the most general sense is a broadly applicable term, so literally speaking, yes, since you are using arrays (1D matrix), you could say the code takes advantage of a construct that can be construed as a vector, thus _vectorized_.  However, a C++ programmer is likely to take issue, or at least [expand on this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/) as the term has very specific terms defining the concept of vectorization.

Comment: FWIW, if I see the term "vectorized code", I normally expect it to refer to compiler-driven loop-level parallelism by way of SIMD. In that context: "Is the above considered 'vectorized code'?": no. It might be *vectorizable* code, but the code is not vectorized until the compiler chooses to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorized code, in the context you seem to be referring to, normally means "an implementation that happens to make use of Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD) hardware instructions".

This can sometimes mean that someone manually wrote a version of a function that is equivalent to the canonical one, but happens to make use of SIMD. More often than not, it's something that the compiler does under the hood as part of its optimization passes.

> In a very high-level language when the data is passed all-at-once (or at least, in bulk chunks) to a lower-level library that does the calculations in faster way. An example of this would be python's use of numpy for array/LA-related stuff.

That's simply not correct. The process of handing off a big chunk of data to some block of code that goes through it quickly is not vectorization in of itself.

You could say "Now that my code uses numpy, it's vectorized" and be sort of correct, but only transitively. A better way to put it would be "Now that my code uses numpy, it runs a lot faster because numpy is vectorized under the hood.". Importantly though, not all fast libraries to which big chunks of data are passed at once are vectorized.

> ...Code examples...

Since there is no SIMD instruction in sight in either example, then neither are vectorized *yet*. It might be true that the second version is more likely to lead to a vectorized program. If that's the case, then we'd say that the program is more *vectorizable* than the first. However, the program is not vectorized until the compiler makes it so.

Comment: if useful for for the `numpy` vectorization examples: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/umath/simd.inc.src

Comment: @David542 I'm not sure I follow. `numpy` being vectorized is not contentious.

Comment: sure I meant in the part where you wrote "...Code examples..." in case the above link was helpful...